# Odata filtering for dynamic models

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, radgrid

I have web api that return data to rad grid
I am using Odata to filter the grid.
this way work with no issue for pre defined table.

I have a dynamic model which return the table object form tblname

the problem when i try to apply odata filter on the query result i got this exception

Could not find a property named 'SubTitle' on type 'System.Object'.

this is my web api code

```
    [HttpGet]
    public PageResult GetforGrid(ODataQueryOptions<dynamic> options, string tblName)
    {
        try
        {
            DynamicTableRep dynamicTableRep = new DynamicTableRep(tblName);
            ODataModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataModelBuilder();
            var dynamicQueryable = dynamicTableRep.GetAll().AsQueryable();
            var results = options.ApplyTo(dynamicQueryable);
            return new PageResult<dynamic>(results as IEnumerable<dynamic>,
                Request.GetNextPageLink(), Request.GetInlineCount());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logs.Log(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

this is the ODataQueryOptions from the beginning of the request 
[image]

this is the result before i apply the filter
[image]